# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token illegal android webview

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, syntax-error

I have a android application , when i run it in my device and starts to look at it, it stops and gives me this msg in logs in eclipse : uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token illegal at file test.html?q=123:1

this is the file test.html that maybe it has the problem :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>my website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">   
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link href="http://www.mysite.com/events-mobile/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.mysite.com/events-mobile/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://www.mysite.com/events-mobile/lib/jquery.1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.mysite.com/events-mobile/lib/purl.js"></script>
    <script>
        // all dialog buttons should close their parent dialog
        $(".ui-dialog button").on("click", function() {     
            $("[data-role='dialog']").dialog("close");      
        });
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
          $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.mysite.com/events-mobile/lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #footerTabs {
            background: #FFF -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #FFF, #dee2e4);
        }
        .ui-listview sup {
            font-size: 0.6em;
            color: #cc0000;
        }
        .ui-page, .ui-mobile-viewport {
    background: url(http://www.mysite.com/events-mobile/images/tiling_stripes_2.gif) repeat;
}

    </style>

</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="eventDetails" data-theme="a">




    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false" style="height: 61px;">
        <a href="venuesdnew.html" data-rel="external" data-position="left"><img src="images/back.png" width="48" style="z-index: 9999; position: fixed;  left:10px;top: 6px;"/></a>

        <div style="margin: 0 auto;width: 150px;left:0;position:absolute;right:0;cursor:pointer;">
         <a href="index.html" data-rel="external" style="display:block;background: red;width:160px;height:40px;position:absolute;left:0px;border:none;box-shadow:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;border-style:none;"><img id="logo" src="images/new-logo.png" width="150" data-position="left">
       </a>
            </div>
    </div>


<div data-role="content">

            <div id="eventNameHeadernew">
            <h1 id="eventNameTitle" style="color:#151ff8;"></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="mainContent">
               <div class="ui-grid-solo">
               <div class="ui-block-anew" id="imageContainer"></div>
               </div>
                <div class="whiteblock" style="height:auto;overflow:hidden;">
                   <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <span class="red" style="float:left;color:#151ff8;">Type:</span>
                   <div class="ui-block-a" id="barinfo" style="float:left;">
                       <span class="red">Type:</span>
                   </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a" id="clubinfo" style="float:left;">
                       <span class="red">Type:</span>
                   </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a" id="loungeinfo" style="float:left;">
                       <span class="red">Type:</span>
                   </div>
                   </div>   
               </div>
               <div class="ui-grid-solo">
               <div class="ui-block-a" id="genre" style="font-size:13px;"></div>
               </div>

               <div class="ui-grid-solo">
               <div class="ui-block-a" id="hours">
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="Fri" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Fri:</td>
        <td class="right" id="friOpen"> </td>
        <td id="friCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="friClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clearrow"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Sat" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Sat:</td>
        <td class="right" id="satOpen"> </td>
        <td id="satCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="satClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="clearrow"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Sun" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Sun:</td>
        <td class="right" id="sunOpen"> </td>
        <td id="sunCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="sunClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="clearrow"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Mon" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Mon:</td>
        <td class="right" id="monOpen"> </td>
        <td id="monCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="monClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="clearrow"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Tue" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Tue:</td>
        <td class="right" id="tueOpen"> </td>
        <td id="tueCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="tueClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="clearrow"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Wed" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Wed:</td>
        <td class="right" id="wedOpen"> </td>
        <td id="wedCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="wedClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="clearrow"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Thu" align="right" class="day" style="color:#151ff8;">Thu:</td>
        <td class="right" id="thuOpen"> </td>
        <td id="thuCenter" class="center">   </td>
        <td id="thuClose" class="right"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>           




               </div>
               </div>
                  <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                  <div class="ui-block-a" id="otherinfo" style="font-weight:bold;"></div></div>
           <div class="ui-grid-solo">           
                <div class="ui-block-a" id="dresscodeinfo" style="font-weight:bold;"></div></div>

                <div class="whiteblock" style="font-weight:bold;">
                    <span class="red"><img src="images/address-icon.jpg" alt=""/></span>
                  <div class="ui-grid-a" style="padding-top:10px;">
                  <div class="ui-block-a" id="address"></div><div id="address2"></div><div id="address3"></div><div id="address4"></div><div id="postcode"></div>
                  <div class="ui-block-b"></div>    
               </div>
            </div>
                <div class="whiteblock" style="overflow:hidden;font-weight:bold;">
                    <span class="red"><img src="images/phone-icon.jpg" style="margin-bottom:5px;" alt=""/><br></span>

                  <div class="ui-block-a" style="padding-top:2px;">
                      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                  <div class="ui-block-a" id="phone" style="font-weight:bold;"></div>
                  <div class="ui-block-b"></div>    
               </div>
            </div>
                      </div>

               <br />
               <div class="ui-grid-solo">
               <div class="ui-block-a" id="directionsButtonContainer"></div>
               </div>
            </div>





        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="venuesdnew.html" data-ajax="false" data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" id="venuesNav" data-icon="custom" >Venues!</a></li>
                <li><a href="eventsdnew.html" data-ajax="false"  data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" id="eventsNav" data-icon="custom">Events!</a></li>
                <li><a href="opennowdnew.html" data-ajax="false" data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" id="opennowNav" data-icon="custom">Open Now</a></li>
                <li><a href="whatson.html" data-ajax="false" data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" id="myeventsNav" data-icon="custom">What's On</a></li> 
                <li><a href="news.html" data-ajax="false" data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" id="newsNav" data-icon="custom">News</a></li>             
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    <script src="js/getvenue.js"></script>

        <script>

    $('#logo').click(function() {
  $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
});


    </script>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and this is the js file :

```
var imagedir = "http://mymsite.com/apps/events/";
var serviceURL = "http://mymsite.com/services/";


$('#eventDetails').bind('pageshow', function(event) {
            var url = $.url(document.location);
            var eventid = url.param("id");





            console.log(eventid);



function getEventDetails() {

   $.ajax({
   url: 'http://mymsite.com/geteventdetails.php',
   data: 'id=' + eventid, 
   datatype:"application/json",
   type:'get',
   cache:false,

   success:function(data){

    console.log(data);
    eventData = $.parseJSON(data);

      if(eventData['image'] == ""){eventData['image'] = "thumbnail.png"}
      $('#eventNameTitle').html(eventData['name']);
      //ANDROID Maps $('#directionsButtonContainer').html('<a type="v" href="geo:0,0?q='+ encodeURIComponent(eventData['postcode']) +'" data-theme="b" data-role="button" id="directionsButton">Directions</a>');
      $('#directionsButtonContainer').html('<a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/?daddr='+ encodeURIComponent(eventData['postcode']) +'" data-theme="b" data-role="button" id="directionsButton">Directions</a>');
      $('#imageContainer').html('<img id="eventHeaderImage" src="'+ imagedir + "/" + eventData['image'] + '"/>');
      $('#genre').html('<div class="whiteblock" style="overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:15px;font-weight:bold;"><span class="red" style="color:#151ff8;">â™ª</span> ' + eventData['genre'].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/"/g, '') + ' ' + '') + '</div>';


      if(eventData['sunOpen'] == ""){eventData['sunOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['monOpen'] == ""){eventData['monOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['tueOpen'] == ""){eventData['tueOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['wedOpen'] == ""){eventData['wedOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['thuOpen'] == ""){eventData['thuOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['friOpen'] == ""){eventData['friOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['satOpen'] == ""){eventData['satOpen'] = "Closed"}
      if(eventData['sunClose'] == ""){eventData['sunClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#sunCenter').html(' - ')}
      if(eventData['monClose'] == ""){eventData['monClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#monCenter').html(' - ')}
      if(eventData['tueClose'] == ""){eventData['tueClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#tueCenter').html(' - ')}
      if(eventData['wedClose'] == ""){eventData['wedClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#wedCenter').html(' - ')}
      if(eventData['thuClose'] == ""){eventData['thuClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#thuCenter').html(' - ')}
      if(eventData['friClose'] == ""){eventData['friClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#friCenter').html(' - ')}
      if(eventData['satClose'] == ""){eventData['satClose'] = " "}
      else{$('#satCenter').html(' - ')}

      $('#friOpen').html( eventData['friOpen']);
      $('#satOpen').html( eventData['satOpen']);
      $('#sunOpen').html( eventData['sunOpen']);
      $('#monOpen').html( eventData['monOpen']);
      $('#tueOpen').html( eventData['tueOpen']);
      $('#wedOpen').html( eventData['wedOpen']);
      $('#thuOpen').html( eventData['thuOpen']);      
      $('#friClose').html( eventData['friClose']);
      $('#satClose').html( eventData['satClose']);
      $('#sunClose').html( eventData['sunClose']);
      $('#monClose').html( eventData['monClose']);
      $('#tueClose').html( eventData['tueClose']);
      $('#wedClose').html( eventData['wedClose']);
      $('#thuClose').html( eventData['thuClose']);


      $('#address').html( eventData['address']);
      $('#address2').html( eventData['address2']);
      $('#address3').html( eventData['address3']);
      $('#address4').html( eventData['address4']);
      $('#postcode').html(eventData['postcode']);

      $('#otherinfo').append('<span class="red" style="color:#151ff8;font-weight:bold;">Other Info: </span>', eventData['otherinfo']);
      $('#phone').append(eventData['phone']);

      $('#dresscodeinfo').html('<span class="red" style="color:#151ff8;padding:0;font-weight:bold;">Dress Code: </span> ' + eventData['dresscode'].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/"/g, '') + ' ' + '');


        $('#barinfo').html('<span class="tags" style="font-weight:bold;  text-style:none; padding-left: 7px;">' + eventData['bar'].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/"/g, '') + ' ' + '');

       $('#clubinfo').html('<span class="tags" style="font-weight:bold;  text-style:none;padding-left: 7px;">' + eventData['club'].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/"/g, '') + ' ' + '');

       $('#loungeinfo').html('<span class="tags" style="font-weight:bold;  text-style:none;padding-left: 7px;">' + eventData['lounge'].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/"/g, '') + ' ' + '');


      $( "#directionsButton" ).buttonMarkup( "refresh" );


          }})

      };
      getEventDetails();
  });
```

all the php pages works fine , everything is ok . except that error , i don't know where is the erroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an syntax error in your JavaScript, missing semicolon for example. Open this web page in your PC browser and check the console for errors or use online validation tools for JavaScript (http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php).

Good luck.